# Force / inform angularJS that the model has updated after we update separate fields from safari extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, safari-extension

I'm building a Safari extension that will auto complete a bunch of fields found on an online form.

That online form is using angularJS to tie in the value in the fields with the value in a model. I don't know much about angularJS, but I could deduce that from the `ng-model=user.firstname.value` etc. directives found in the input tags.

My Safari extension will get the first name input field, and set `firstNameField.val("A first name")` in order to add a value in that field.

However, this doesn't seem to update the angularJS model, since if I am to exit that field manually, it'll color itself red, saying there is no data, even though there clearly is some text.

From my extension, I don't seem to be able to access the `angular` object unfortunately, so I cannot call the methods that I read need to be called (`angular.$apply`).

Seems like what I am trying to do is doable, since the LastPass extension correctly adds values to the input fields and causes the model to be correctly updated – the fields don't color themselves red.

Comment: Seems like this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3133 is a similar discussion

Comment: The only way i can think of right now, is to add a directive to the input field which observes changes via the native javascript event `onchange`, which then calls `$scope.$apply` so that the model is updated with the new info.

Comment: @RobinJonsson I can't get the $scope variable

Comment: if you made a directive then yes it will have it's own `$scope` inherited from the parent scope.

Comment: @RobinJonsson How would I go about making a directive?